# Hide show div based on selected value in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have one vuejs drodown, now I want to hide and show my dive based on dropdown selected value.
Hers is my code but it's working for only one id, not for all. I want to hide show my div from here based on option modal value
I.e - If my modal value is 1 then it should be show only test_1 divs

```
<template>
  <div>
    <multiselect
      v-model="optionsData[0]"
      :options="optionsData"
      :custom-label="nameWithLang"
      placeholder="Pick some"
      label="data"
      track-by="data" 
      @change="hideshowdiv"/>
  </div>
  <div id="test_1">test 1</div>
  <div id="test_1">test 1</div>
  <div id="test_1">test 1</div>
  <div id="test_1">test 1</div>
  <div id="test_1">test 1</div>
  <div id="test_2">test 2</div>
  <div id="test_2">test 2</div>
  <div id="test_2">test 2</div>
  <div id="test_2">test 2</div>
  <div id="test_2">test 2</div>
</template>

export default {
  components: {
    Multiselect,
    InputTag
  },
  data: () => ({
    optionsData: [
      { id: '1', data: 'Value1' },
      { id: '2', data: 'Value2' }
    ],
  }),
  method() {
    hideshowdiv(value) {
      document.getElementById("test_" + value).style.display = "block";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: 1. `document.getElementById` will return 1 element only. You can use css class and `document.querySelectorAll` combined to achieve what you want. But 2. and more importantly this is old school way of showing and hiding divs. In `vue` you can use `v-if` to show and hide elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using **v-if**

update your HTML like below using **v-if**

```
<div id="test_1" v-if="selectedValue == 1">test 1</div>
  <div id="test_1" v-if="selectedValue == 1">test 1</div>
  <div id="test_1" v-if="selectedValue == 1">test 1</div>
  <div id="test_1" v-if="selectedValue == 1">test 1</div>
  <div id="test_1" v-if="selectedValue == 1">test 1</div>
  <div id="test_2" v-if="selectedValue == 2">test 2</div>
  <div id="test_2" v-if="selectedValue == 2">test 2</div>
  <div id="test_2" v-if="selectedValue == 2">test 2</div>
  <div id="test_2" v-if="selectedValue == 2">test 2</div>
  <div id="test_2" v-if="selectedValue == 2">test 2</div>
```

then declare **selectedValue** variable, you can also assign default value to it

```
data: () => ({
    optionsData: [
      { id: '1', data: 'Value1' },
      { id: '2', data: 'Value2' }
    ],
    selectedValue: Number
  })
```

and in method assign value to selectedValue

```
method() {
hideshowdiv(value) {
  this.selectedValue = value;
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make all the divs "display:none" before make your div "display: block".
It's not changed "display:none" automatically.